# In visual stdio 2019 C++ i tried to open an empty peject but it didnt worked out....?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

//Simple code 
When i tried this code in An empty project so an error came of

> the file specified is  not found

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hell world";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `the file specified is not found` At which step, and what is the *complete* error message?

Answer (score -1):

Did you notice this `#include<iostream>` it should be like this `#include<iostream.h>`. I think it's not a problem with visual studio.

Comment: it usually goes with both.

Answer (score -1):

You want to see the command prompt to say hello world. Therefore you should chose the console application in the option while creating the project not an empty project.

So if you will chose the option/template of console application that will do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).